# App was rejected cause non-public API in Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios, publishing

My app was rejected by Apple this week because of the following non-public APIs

- nextStartIndex
- canGoOffline

I did find the **nextStartIndex** in Google Client API, and I renamed it to **_nextStartIndex**.

But I can not find **canGoOffline** anywhere. The reviewer of Apple indicated that it was used by **[GMSServices checkReadyForOffline]** which is provided by Google Maps SDK for iOS. What can I do now? I can not fix this issue as I did on nextStartIndex since there is no way to get source code of it.

I think there are lots of Apps integrated Google Maps SDK, they should encounter the same problem. But after searching for a while online, I did not find any information helpful.

This problem occurred after I upgraded Google Maps SDK for iOS to version 2.0.1. Reverse the SDK to a previous version is a possible solution. But is there any other better way?

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Anderson

Comment: I'm having the same problem -- with nextStartIndex only -- using:
GoogleMaps (1.13.2) 
GooglePlacesAPI (1.0.6)

But I don't see nextStartIndex anywhere.

Comment: looks like I am wrong, but I never have this problem before with 1.13.2. Anyway, some guy suggested to add a method canGoOffline to AppDelete, and just return false, he got passed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a false positive and Google are working on a new version of the SDK.
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10393

In the mean time if using Obj-C put this in your App Delegate.

```
-(BOOL)canGoOffline{return false;}
```

Or Swift...

```
func canGoOffline() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```